# Docker-compose and node container as not the primary one

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and I've successfully set up the PHP/Apache/MySQL. But once I try to add the `node` container (in order to use `npm`) it always shuts the container down upon composing up. And yes, I understand that I can use `node` directly without involving `docker`, but I find it useful for myself.

And as for `composer`, I want to use volumes in the `node` container in order to persist `node_modules` inside of `src` folder.

I compose it up using `docker-compose up -d --build` command.
During composing it shows no errors (even `node` container seems to be successfully built).
If it might help, I can share the log file (it's too big to include it here).

PS. If you find something that can be improved, please let me know.
Thank you in advance!

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get install zip unzip zlib1g-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer global require laravel/installer
ENV PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:${PATH}"
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - nodejs
    ports:
      - 80:80

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql:db
    ports:
      - 8765:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  nodejs:
    image: node:9.11
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/773be66016fd1ff4a860529a80af61277f75c7e2/9/Dockerfile) Dockerfile you are using shows, you are not actually runing any application in the node container so as soon as it builds and starts up - it shuts down because it has nothing else to do.

Solution is simple - provide a application that you want to run into the container and run it like:

*I've modified a part of your compose file*

```
  nodejs:
    image: node:9.11
    command: node app.js
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Where `app.js` is the script in which your app is written, you are free to use your own name.

**edit** providing a small improvement you asked for

You are not waiting until your database is fully initialized (`depends_on` is not capable of that), so take a look at one of my previous answers dealing with that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401262/3425640)

Comment: Right now I don't need node to run as a standalone container. It's going to be used as npm only. So I put that empty `app.js` into `src` folder and ran compose. The result remains the same.