# A way to check Oracle finished sql

Tags: database, oracle, docker, docker-compose, oracle12c

I've got Docker Compose cluster and one of the containers is Oracle 12c. There is schema.sql file to initialize the db. I would like my application to wait until the db executes all the sql. How can I do it in an automatic fashion with bash?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to explain here, but I'll link one of my previous answers for a similar problem - steps are actually the same because only the database service and background differs.

**1)**
First thing is, you have to provide a bash script that will wait until a service will respond via http. In databases it usually happens when DB is ready to go and all initializations are done.

the [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) script written by **vishnubob** in his *wait-for-it* repo @ github.

**2)** 
Second thing, you have to get that script inside each container that requires your DB.

**3)** 
Third, you specify a `entrypoint` in your compose file, that will execute the waiting script before the actual `command` running your service will trigger.

example of a entrypoint (as reference to the answer I link to)

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sh -c './wait-for-it.sh oracle:3306 -t 30'
exec "$@"
```

All these steps are explained in detail [here in scenario 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338581/password-authentication-failed-for-user-in-docker-postgres-image/50338995#50338995), be aware of a reference to my another answer inside the answer I'm pointing at here. This issue is a very common problem for beginners and takes quite a lot of explanation, so I cannot post it all here.

**note** here concerning `depends_on` which you might think is a native solution for this problem from docker - as docs state, it only waits until the container is running, not actually finished it's internal jobs - docker is not aware of how much there is to be done.

Comment: @trusr512 thx for the answer! But the problem is with the bash script itself) I mean I’m using wait-for-it but I don’t think there is some http endpoint to share information about sql execution

Comment: You are right, but http endpoint is only available when all the initial jobs inside DB finish executing.

Comment: I see but it seems that’s not the case for Oracle) I was trying to listen on 8080 port but no luck