# How should I be sure DB is up before starting my app with docker compose 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a classic PHP 7 / MySQL / Nginx API that I want to dockerise

Thing is when I run my docker compose, app starts before db is ready, so it fails:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: jaumo
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  app:
    image: repo/myimage
    environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
          - "db"
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) states:

> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.
>
> Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.

So basically, in version 2, I could add the heathcheck condition, it was quite easy, but now, I don't know how to do, and docs doesn't give any replacement method.

How should I do? It is a pretty common case...

Comment: Have you tried consistently using the same indentation in your YML files?

Answer (score 1):

I described the process in detail in a few of my previous answers as it takes a little explanation. Here is a [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401262/3425640). Basically you write a `wait-for-it` script that waits until http is responding - then and only then databases like postgres/oracle/mysql are ready to work.

Comment: you mean, like this : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ ... I find it more hacky than having a health-check for my service...

Comment: Looks nice, both require a little bash-scripting, the only difference is "my method" puts you in a docker-way of setting up prerequisites for a given service - in a separate place (`entrypoint`). I haven't yet seen a professional project not utilize `entrypoint`s in favour of customizing a run script. I'm not banning the solution you found, myself I wouldn't use it because of kill signals handling, Docker states to be careful with writing custom run scripts and be sure to handle all system singals you might want to act on.