# SpringBoot on Docker unable to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot

I have written docker compose for my SpringBoot app with MySQL. When I run docker-compose up eventually I get an error:

```
 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:325) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      ... 69 common frames omitted
  Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:172) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
      ... 70 common frames omitted
  Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

At first I thought the the cause was the db but I managed to run local instance of the app and connect to the docker mysql.
Next I assumed that the spring app tries to connect to mysql before it is up and running but I restarted the app (mysql was already running) and got the same error.
Currently I think that this might be caused by the windows10 firewall but I am running low on ideas.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
LABEL maintainer="maciej"
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/kamienica.jar /app/kamienica.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","kamienica.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=maciej
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=kamienica
      - MYSQL_USER=maciej
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=maciej
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql
    ports:
    - 3333:3306
    container_name: kamienica-db
  kamienica-app:
    image: kamienica-image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /data/spring-boot-app
    container_name: kamienica-app
```

and the application-docker.properties:

```
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://kamienica-db:3333/kamienica?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.username = maciej
jdbc.password = maciej
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
```

Comment: Your MySQL Db is down

Comment: Then how come I can connect to it via MySQL workbench as well as local instance of an app that points to it?

Comment: Maciek, most probably it's the DB initialization process. Why is it possible that other tools are working? When you first fire off your app, Java is yet unable to connect to the DB, you then try with other tools but the DB is already up and running so the other tools see no problem. It's a very common misconfiguration of a compose file. Can help with that if interested.

Comment: Check out my answer to a very similar problem [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400423/a-way-to-check-oracle-finished-sql/50401262#50401262), to see exactly what do I mean.

Comment: @trust512 I also suspected that but I tried to restart the app while the mysql container was up for a while and got the same error

Comment: Then try `exec`'ing into the java container and `ping` the DB container from inside the Java container to see if it's at least reachable - if not, then you're right, and that'd mean some network issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change the url into this your properties file

> jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/kamienica

Answer (score 2):

jdbc:mysql://[mysql-docker-container-name]:[mysql-port]/[db-name]

in your docker-compose.yml mysql-docker-container-name is mysql-docker-container

so change your spring boot application.properties file mysql url as following

jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/kamienica